# App Engine, items disappearing from search index

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using App Engine, Python, v1.9.23.290

Currently I'm doing Alpha testing before opening up the app to the public.

I'm finding that some items "randomly" disappear from the search index.

I'm looking at one particular item where a user entered the item a week ago.
The search index was updated.
The item showed up as expected in searches.
The NDB entity was no "touched"/modified since last week.
This morning it is not in the index.

I don't have a code sample to share, because there is no "error".

Is this a common problem with a common solution?

To clarify:
When a user creates/edits an NDB entity, I update the item index thusly:

```
doc = search.Document(doc_id=str(this_item.key.id()), fields=fields)
search_index = search.Index(name="ItemIndex")
try:
    search_index.put(doc)
except search.Error:
    logging.exception('Put failed on search index ItemIndex')
```

All is fine.  But the item 'disappeared' from the index.

With only a dozen items in the index I've had this happen a couple of times in the last week.

If it never happens for anybody else, I guess that is a good sign.  I just have to find where the error is in my code.

If somebody else has had this problem, any indication as to the problem would be a great help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. We have been using NDB and search index for long time and haven't had items disappear

Comment: Good to know.  I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I see my problem.  Each item entity is parented to the user that created the item.  Two items with different parents can have the same ID number.  The ID number is the unique identifier for the search API.  So I'm writing over the index items.  Parenting to the user gives me immidiate consistancy but stomps on my search id.   ...pondering solutions.

Comment: Use `doc_id=this_item.key.urlsafe()`; on retrieval, rebuild the key with the `k=ndb.Key(urlsafe=...)` ctor, then `k.get()` -- that gives you strong consistency without needing ancestor queries, too, if the consistency issue is the only reason you're using ancestor queries.

Comment: Oh man, that sounds like a wickedly simple fix.  Checking it out now.  Thanks!

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.